Filter mailing lists in groovy
I have the following mailing list setup in my project pom.xml:
<mailingLists>
    <mailingList>
        <name>slackChannel</name>
        <subscribe>test-channel</subscribe>
    </mailingList>
</mailingLists>

I would like to pickup and retrieve the subscribe property in my Jenkins pipeline. I am also trying to filter mailing list to where name equals slackChannel. But I get this exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more variables have some issues with their values: MAVEN_MAILING_LIST. I'm not very familiar with groovy so could use some help with the code below:
MAVEN_POM_MODEL = readMavenPom() // requires plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/

MAVEN_MAILING_LIST = MAVEN_POM_MODEL?.getMailingLists().findAll({it.getName() == "slackChannel"}).get(0).getMailingList().getSubscribe()

Thanks!

What's MAVEN_POM_MODEL?

It is from this plugin -  https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/

Your expression is unnecessarily complex:
MAVEN_POM_MODEL?.getMailingLists().findAll({it.getName() == "slackChannel"}).get(0).getMailingList().getSubscribe()

but basically get(0) returns a MailingList, and it doesn't have a getMailingList() method. Could be simplified:
MAVEN_POM_MODEL.getMailingLists().find({it.getName() == "slackChannel"}.getSubscribe()

On an unrelated note: once you start using safe navigation ?. all the chained navigation operators should also be safe, since you explicitly allowed null to be passed on. In Groovy it's largely unnecessary with built-in collections due to NullObject, but with other classes it might be useful.
